# how can I join a Scalding ValuePipe to a TypedPipe?

Tags: scala, hadoop, cluster-analysis, scalding

I've adapted the scalding KMeans example to do KModes. The problem is that when the job is complete, I need to join the clustered records with the matching centroids. The KMeans code uses a ValuePipe to hold the centroids. 
So to get the centroids out of the ValuePipe, I'm flatmapping it.
Then I do the join like this:

```
  HVKModes(500000,inputSets,10).waitFor(Config.default,mode) match {
    case Success((a,centroids: ValuePipe[List[LabeledCentroid]], points: TypedPipe[LabeledVector])) => {
      val joined = centroids
        .flatMap {
          cs : List[LabeledCentroid] => {
          val t = TypedPipe.from(cs)
          Iterator(points.join(t)) }
        }
        .values
        .write(clusteredOutput)
    }
    case Failure(e) => sys.error("problem running job:" + e.toString)
  }
```

The problem is that the compiler gives a type error on the "values" line:

```
Cannot prove that com.twitter.scalding.typed.CoGrouped[Int,((String, Set[String]), Set[String])] <:< (Any, V).
[error]         .values
```

I gather that the error indicates it can't figure out the V which I take to mean the values. But what should I do about that?

Answer (score 1):

I almost had it right. I just needed to join on the *result* of the flatmapping.

```
  HVKModes(500000,inputSets,10).waitFor(Config.default,mode) match {
    case Success((a,centroids: ValuePipe[List[LabeledCentroid]], points: TypedPipe[LabeledVector])) => {

      val cs  =
        centroids
        .flatMap {
          cs : List[LabeledCentroid] => { cs.toIterator}
        }

      points
        .join(cs)
        .values
        .write(clusteredOutput)
    }
    case Failure(e) => sys.error("problem running job:" + e.toString)
  }
```